# how to change selected option of textbox based on datareader result vb

Tags: vb.net

.hi everyone I have this code:

```
Private Sub EditPage_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'InventorySysDataSet.tb_master_products' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Tb_master_productsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventorySysDataSet.tb_master_products)
    sqlCnn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEREY\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=InventorySys;Integrated Security=SSPI")

    Me.txtRowId.Text = Form1.txtRowId.Text
    'MsgBox(Me.txtRowId.Text)
    sql = "Select * from tb_master_inventory_per_day where Inventory_Date = " & txtRowId.Text & ""

    Dim upcmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from tb_master_inventory_per_day where Row_Id = @Row_Id", sqlCnn)
    upcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Row_Id", Me.txtRowId.Text))
    upcmd.Connection.Open()
    Try
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = upcmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read Then
            txtInventoryDate.Text = dr.Item("Inventory_Date")
            cboProductCode.DisplayMember = dr.Item("Product_Code")
            txtQty.Text = dr.Item("Product_Count")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Error!")
        End If
    Catch ex As SqlException
        If ex.Number <> 0 Then
            'ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.txtuseridprofile, "Login Id: " &
            'Me.txtuseridprofile.Text & " :Not Found!")
            upcmd.Connection.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Try
    upcmd.Connection.Close()


End Sub
```

what i want to do is to automatically change the selected option of the cboProductCode on page load depending on the result of a query executed onload also.
help pls! TIA!

Comment: Are we talking client side or server side? Perhaps you can post the section of code which does there query, and show us where or when you want the DropDownList to update (it is a DropDownList we're talking about, isn't it?).

Answer (score 0):

.Haha! it's funny that i have tried so many ways but not tried using cboProductCode.Text instead of cboProductCode.DisplayMember. It now works! :D